# Any clue why I cant seem to get the correct answer after pressing "play again"?

Tags: javascript, dom

As you can see from the complexity of the program I am new to this but I've heard this is the best place to ask!

```
'use strict'

//DOM Elements declaration.
const square = document.getElementById("color1")
const guesses = document.getElementsByClassName("guess");
const guessArr = [...guesses]
const playAgain = document.querySelector(".play-again");
const title = document.getElementById("title")

var playing = true;

init();


function init() {
    let pickedColor = createColor();
    console.log(pickedColor);
    title.innerHTML = "GUESS THE COLOUR!"
    square.style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
    playing = true;
    updateGuesses(pickedColor);
    guess(pickedColor);
}

//Setting the playing field.
function createColor () {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255); 
    let color = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
    return color
}

function updateGuesses (pickedColor) {
    for (let i=0; i < 3; i++){
        guesses[i].textContent = createColor() // Button[0] = rgb(random, random, random)...
    }
    //Pick a random button at runtime and make it the right guess.
    let correct = guesses[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    correct.textContent = pickedColor 
}

//Playing the game
function guess(pickedColor){
    guessArr.forEach((guess) => {
        guess.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log(guess.textContent);
            if (playing){
                if (guess.textContent == pickedColor){
                    title.innerHTML = "You Win "
                    playing = false;
                    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
                } else {
                    title.innerHTML = "YOU LOSE ❌"
                    playing = false;
                }
            } 
        })
    });
}

playAgain.addEventListener("click", init)
```

In the code above. The game seems to work the first time around. If I select the correct colour, It will appear with "You Win!". However, unless I manually refresh the page, I can never seem to get the winning condition again regardless of if I press the correct answer.

Ive uploaded the project onto codepen to help visualise what im talking about as im unsure this code will be enough. Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/remcrw/pen/ExRObWG

It works with global variables for the pickedColor but I was trying to clean up my code and see if I could minimise the use of global variables and this is where I encountered the problem.

Comment: Not sure yet why but what is happening that every round your pickedColor variable has the same value as in the first round.

Comment: Yes, I realised this too this weekend. I havent found an answer as to why yet either. Possibly the functions are being called first before the new color has been set meaning that the text content of the guesses and the value of pickedColor will never be the same. Maybe something to do with passing by reference vs passing by value?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Maybe you fixed it already? I am able to win, click "play again", and then win again.

Comment: Yes the codepen version now works due to the global pickedColour variable, however when using the code from the snippet above it fails to work.